# Any example with Protocol Buffers + GWT?

Tags: gwt, protocol-buffers

Do you know about any example using together Google Protocol Buffers and GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2649) in the GWT issue tracker regarding this. See also jrmerz's comment (comment 16 in the issue) and [his attempts](http://justinexb.blogspot.com/2009/09/client-side-google-protocol-buffers-gwt.html) at using protobufs in GWT.